# How to Set each line's value of a Multiline EditText Field in Java file

Tags: android, android-widget

if EditText Field has 4 lines.which i set in xml.How to Set each line value in Java file???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    EditText edit  =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.test1);
    edit.setText("line1\n");
    edit.setText(edit.getText()+"lin2\n");
    edit.setText(edit.getText()+"lin3\n");
    edit.setText(edit.getText()+"lin4\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know how many lines you want to display in screen and each line has specific text than my suggestion would be to use seperate EditText for each line.

Comment: You mean i have to create separate EditText field for individual text line?

Comment: It will be good if you know actual number and actual text to be displayed , than use sepearte EditText

Answer (score 1):

```
    EditText ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    ed.setText("line1 \n");
    ed.setText("line2 \n");
    ed.setText("line3 \n");
    ed.setText("line4 \n");
```